# Creating a 3D TIN or similar 3D Delaunay triangulation in R

Tags: r, topography, delaunay, triangulation

Background: I have topographical datasets with height information as a starting point. The endgame is to create a dataset of triangulations which I can use to import into Parasolid to be used further downstream. The takeaway point is that I need triangles.

More about the data: The data is of the type Large SpatialLinesDataFrame which represents topographical maps. I have some experience with converting this to spatialpoints/interpolating/rasterising etc., so this is not the crux of the problem. I understand the problems that arise (or don't) whether the data is regularly or irregularly spaced and am confident I would be able to coax the data between the two as required, so this is also not the crux of the problem.

The problem: Regardless of what the data format, I can't seem to find a library in R that would be able to calculate Delaunay (or any suitable) triangulations. Yes, there is `deldir` and `RTriangle` but both these are limited to datasets in the same plane i.e 2D. Mountains tend to be 3D, so therein lies my problem.

Comment: Create a 2-d triangulation and then sample the height information at each triangle vertex (eg from a rasterised DEM) to get the height. GIS representations of height fields tend to be "2.5D" (ie xy + height) rather than fully 3d modelled surfaces that can handle things like overhangs.

Comment: Did you try [delaunayn](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geometry/versions/0.4.1/topics/delaunayn)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall "N-dimensions" This looks exactly like what I need. Don't know how I missed that. It's even in the standard c-ran libraries! Library installed and I will have a go at it today. Will promote your suggestion to an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @KirkKuykendall It took me a while to get to this. Had to update RStudio, R and RTools just to that I can install the rgl library in order to use plot3d to plot the result of delaunayn. Anyway, can you add your comment as a proper answer, as it did answer my question on point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Delaunay Triangulation In N Dimensions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geometry/versions/0.4.1/topics/delaunayn).